# Generate an array of objects from all the rows and columns in WPF grid control on a coded UI test C#

Tags: visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests

Trying to generate an array of objects from WPF grid taking all rows and its corresponding cells data, in the visual studio 2015 coded UI test, for testing a desktop application with the grid controls.

Basically, i'm trying to search, locate and click the cell on a WPF grid on the basis of string value i have which is supposed to be present in some particular cell.

And this is a c# test method where i'm trying to get the data:

```
    [TestMethod]  
    public void GridInteractions()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations

        //This is my grid control from 'UIMap.uitest' control repository            
        var gridControl = this.MainWindow.MainPanel.GridPanel;

        #endregion

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`GetChildren`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.uitestcontrol.getchildren.aspx) method will return a `UITestControlCollection` with all the immediate descendants of a control. The items you want may be descendants (of descendants  of descendants ... ) of them. They might be found by adding  the following to your code:

```
UITestControlCollection children = gridControl.GetChildren();
```

It may be worth doing a recursive descent from `gridControl` using `GetChildren` to get the required values. Alternatively if you know the exact hierarchy of the controls then, if only two levels are needed, you might use code of the style:

```
UITestControlCollection children = gridControl.GetChildren();
foreach ( UITestControl child in children )
{
    UITestControlCollection grandChildren = child.GetChildren();
    foreach ( UITestControl grandChild in grandChildren )
    {
        ... process the grandchild ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks man for the response but doing a descendant recursive, at some point, 'UITestControl' doesn't get you any children before i get the rows or cells that i actually want.

Trying to automate our application using Coded UI which is using the [FarPoint Spread tool](http://farpoint-spread.software.informer.com/8.0/). And I am trying Coded UI on SpreadControl but it is not providing me ROWS, or COLUMNS acces in a grid like finding the cell on the basis of 'String'
or click #number Column or rows. Can you help me here how to proceed ahead?

Comment: @Omm Perhaps the rows and columns are within a custom control that does not support Coded UI. When you use the Coded UI record and generate tool can it see into the cells, or does it just see the whole control as one item? If the latter then you need to ask the author of the control about what support it has for Coded UI.

Comment: Yeah it see the whole sheet as one single item (as in canvas). Checked for the solution in the author's forum and they say it doesn't support Coded UI automation as of now. I was actually looking for an alternative. Anyways thanks :)

Comment: @Omm Is your application required to be useable by people with visual impairments or those who cannot use a keyboard and mouse? Coded UI uses the same mechanisms as some of the tools like screen readers and other input devices. I believe that some countries require applications and web site to be useable by people with disabilities. This might influence  your choice of spreadsheet support and it may be something the spreadsheet's author should consider.